# OpenTok JS connection sampleQos issue in Chrome (mobile)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opentok

Have connection sampleQos OpenTok issue.

This error happens only in Chrome mobile view.

```
VM1645 opentok.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError:
Cannot read property 'sampleQos' of undefined
```

Btw, the same appears in this [demo](https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/React-Basic-Video-Chat/)

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: screen]

Comment: Hi there, Adam from the OpenTok team here. Thank you for finding this issue. I have filed a bug internally and we will take a look into it.

Comment: @AdamUllman Can you please point us to where we can be updated about this?

Comment: When we do a release we update the release notes with details. https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/release-notes.html

Comment: You can also subscribe to new release announcements here https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/sections/201722216-New-Releases

Comment: I'll update this Stackoverflow post as well though once we have a fix.

Comment: @AdamUllman, waiting for your update, thank you a lot!

Comment: We released a fix for this now! https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/release-notes.html#fixedIssues

Comment: @AdamUllman this fixed. Thank you a lot!